# Resampling - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecast

I'm trying to forecast retail sales time series using python. Data set contains the following attributes,
[Order date
Ship mode
Segment
Customer ID
Category
Product ID 
Product name
Sales 
Quantity
Discount
Profit].
Here I have imported the dataset and I have indexed with time series data

```
prdct1 = prdct1.groupby('Order Date')['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
prdct1 = prdct1.set_index('Order Date')
prdct1.index
```

Date time index has been displayed for the above code.
When I try to resample the average daily sales value for start of each month as a timestamp,

```
y = prdct1['Sales'].resample('MS').mean()
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `DatetimeIndex` by converting column `Order Date` before your solution, also `reset_index` with `set_index` should be omit:

```
prdct1['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(prdct1['Order Date'])
prdct1 = prdct1.groupby('Order Date')['Sales'].sum()
```

And then:

```
y = prdct1.resample('MS').mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with the above code, I'm getting the following error, 
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

 
KeyError: 'Sales'

Comment: @SandhyaEashwar - Sorry, you need `y = prdct1.resample('MS').mean()`